# Как открыть лог файл в python?

Tags: python, логирование

Как открыть лог файл с помощью python? Пример
Например,

```
C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

Я так же делал:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете это сделать с помощью текстового редактора

Щёлкнуть правой кнопкой по файлу -> открыть с помощью -> выберете блокнот

Если Вам это нужно сделать с помощью python, то следует поступить как с обыным текстовым файлом:

```
with open('C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log') as fd:
    lines = fd.readlines()

print(lines)
```

Comment: Я так же делал.

Comment: @FunnySad вот и хорошо.

Comment: Я понял, надо было подождать,т.к. файл большой

Comment: @FunnySad, если ответ вам помог, то [проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)